# How to obtain references to Identity and Trust stores defined for Weblogic domain?

Tags: ssl, weblogic, keystore

We run application on Weblogic 12 server. We defined Identity Store and Trust Store on a domain level.

How do we obtain references to java.security.KeyStore (should correspond to the Identity Store)
and java.security.KeyStore (should correspond to the Trust Store) in JEE environment without explicitly using filenames and passwords for these keyStores?

The Identity and Trust store filenames are different on production and test environments and are password protected.
We want to avoid referring the jks files by name and reading passwords from property files (they are already set when defining the key stores in the domain)

I am building a jersey 2 client application with two way SSL running on the Weblogic server and need the keystores for the SslConfigurator object.

Comment: All these informations are available from the Server mbean. Take a look at the [mbean reference documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/wls/WLMBR/core/index.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I will look into it. Thanks